# How to define a new org-babel-execute function for a new major mode?

Tags: org-mode

I want to be able to run code in org mode using the major mode defined in the [nand2tetris](https://github.com/CestDiego/nand2tetris.el) package. How can I write an `org-babel-execute` function to do this?

Comment: It is explained [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html#develop). I would recommend you to also look at `ob-shell` for example usage, and to use `edebug` for figuring out what is happening.